# Ancla enlace a diferente página no carga estilos

Tags: html, css, html5

Hola a todos mis estimad@s.

He integrado un enlace ancla en mi página web, redirige a donde corresponde, pero por alguna razón no carga los estilos. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link fw-bold nav-servicios dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            SERVICIOS
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/proyecto/servicios.php/#ancla-internet">Internet</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/proyecto/servicios.php/#ancla-kualitv">KualiTV</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="speedtest.php">Speed Test</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Esta es la ancla.

```
<div class="container py-4">
            <h1 class="text-center display-5 fw-bold text-conectate" id="ancla-internet">Conéctate con todo  lo que te gusta</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center fst-italic fw-bold text-fibra">Todo lo que realices sin interrupciones con internet de fibra óptica</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Pon todo el código. Con lo que has puesto es difícil hacer pruebas, menciona si usas algún Framework también.